# Getting one value to a val in Scala out of SQL database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, scala, playframework

I'm using play framework with postgreSQL, and trying to get only one value out of a specific row and column in a table.
The program has no trouble compiling the code, but when the action with this code is called, it just doesn't work. The SQL query works fine, I checked it in psql.

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    val selectSalt: Option[String] = SQL("""
    select salt from devices
    where principal_id=(
              select id from principals 
              where principal={id})
    """).on(
    'id -> user).as(scalar[String].singleOpt)
```

...(there is more code underneath)

Comment: Is it possible you are getting back multiple rows rather than just 1? user I presume is an Int or Long to match the id? As others have asked, what is the exact error that you receive?

Comment: I found out that the value i was trying to get was null, I filled it out and the code worked. But why wouldn't it work when null?

Comment: If the value is null `selectSalt` should have contained a `None`. Don't know why it wasn't executing your println.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scalar[String]` works well for me, along the lines of

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("""
    select salt from devices
    where principal_id=(
      select id from principals 
      where principal={id})
  """).on('id -> user)
  .as(scalar[String].singleOpt) match {
    case Some(selectSalt) => println("Do something with selectSalt")
    case _ => println("No selectSalt found with id="+user)
  }
```

You could use a `limit 1` in the SQL if there's any chance of multiple rows satisfying the `principle={id}` condition. Instead of the `match` you could also do a `getOrElse`, depending how you want to handle the no rows/null condition:

```
.as(scalar[String]).singleOpt).getOrElse("") // No Salt found with given id
```

Comment: I tried the second one with the getOrElse, but when there are null values the program freezes, like before:
`val selectSignature: String = SQL(
  """
  select signature from devices
  where principal_id=(select id from principals where principal={id})
  """).on(
  'id -> user).as(scalar[String].singleOpt).getOrElse("null")`

Comment: what versions of play, scala and postgresql do you have - could be some funny...? can you share your db table and case class definitions too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
.as(str("salt").singleOpt)
```

Comment: do you get an error? what do you get in selectSalt?

Comment: The program just stops without doing anything, I have a println command afterwards that doesnt show